# Statement has no effect(Python)

Tags: python-3.x

program to get a string from a given string where all occurrences of its first char have been changed to '$', except the first char itself.
Sample String : 'restart'
Expected Result : 'resta$t'

here's my code

```
    def change(string):
        string_len = len(string)
        t = string[0]
        for each in range(1, string_len):
            if each is t:
                each == '$'
            else:
                continue
    return string

print(change("restart"))

output
restart
```

i'using Pycharm. Line no 6 (each == '$')says this statement has no effect. i don't want to use replace method. just want to know what is the problem.

Comment: `==` is a *comparison*, which you ignore the result of.  I suspect you meant `=` for *assignment*, but that wouldn't work either: `each` holds a copy of each element of the string in turn, assigning to it changes only `each`, not the original string.  Changing the string is impossible, anyway; that's simply not how strings work in Python.  Something that generates a new string, such as the `.replace()` method, is the only way to make changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code commented:

```
    def change(string):
        string_len = len(string)
        t = string[0]
        for each in range(1, string_len):
            if each is t: # To compara strings you should use the == operator not the 'is' operator.
                each == '$' # This will not have any effect because is a temporal variable visible just inside the 'for' loop and you are not using it.
            else:
                continue
    return string

print(change("restart"))
```

A solution could be:

```
def change(s):
    result = ''
    for character in s:
        result += '$' if character == s[0] else character
    return result


print(change('restart'))
```

Python strings are immutable objects, so you can't do `'aaa'[1] = 'b'` to get `aba`.

Answer (score -1):

`each` is set to an integer and you are comparing it to a string.